# where is the docusign api tab label wildcard matching documentation

Tags: docusignapi

In the api you can select multiple fields with something like this:

```
Text text = new Text();
text.setTabLabel("\\*_broker");
```

This will apply settings to all textfields that have names that end with "_broker".
But i want to select ALL text fields in the entire document and "\\*" does not seem to work.

Can anyone tell me how to select all fields from the API, or even better point me to the documentation for the setTabLabel matching format.

I've look all over and it seems alot of the old documentation links no longer work.

Thanks.

Comment: You want to populate all text fields with the same value?

Comment: We are trying to assign ALL PDF form fields to all recipients.  This is all done dynamically through the API, using the document.transformPdfFields("true");

we don't always know the field names but we want all fields to be editable by all parties (recipients).  Maybe there is an easier way, but i cannot find it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can assign assign all transformed form fields to the first recipient by making them the default recipient (set `defaultRecipient` to `true`).

In order to make all of those form fields Collaborative, I believe you'll need to make extra API calls:

First, create the envelope as a draft (`status = created` instead of `sent`).

Then make a call to get the list of all the tabs ([EnvelopeRecipients::List](https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/reference/Envelopes/EnvelopeRecipients/list/) with `include_tabs=true`)

Finally, Use the tabLabels (or IDs) in an [Envelopes::Update](https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/reference/Envelopes/Envelopes/update/) call to add the `"shared": "true"` parameter to each of them, and update the `status` to `sent` to actually send it.

Comment: Thanks for the reponse, that's exactly what i'm doing without the "save as draft and iterating" the thing is it works without saving as draft if i use a wildcard like "\\*_broker" and set shared=true, then all the *_broker fields will be collaboriative.  That's why i was looking for a way to select all fields.  It saves us those extra steps.  But if there is no way to select all, then i will do it how you suggested. Thanks.